# How does one search for 32-bit application in winget?

Tags: package-managers, winget

Installing a 32-bit can be done by the following command:
`winget install <application> -a x86`

But how do you search to check if that application already exists in the system before installing it again. I have 64 & 32 bit installed of same application but their naming and Id are very much the same.

`winget list --id <application> -a x86` ???